# Theme/Style/Text appearance, which one takes precedent?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

As my title, when I'm using a theme, style or text appearance, which one takes precedent?

Is there any way I can use all three of them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes), the priorities are as follows:

1. Applying character- or paragraph-level styling via text spans to
   TextView-derived classes
2. Applying attributes programmatically
3. Applying individual attributes directly to a View
4. Applying a style to a View
5. Default styling
6. Applying a theme to a collection of Views, an activity, or your
   entire app
7. Applying certain View-specific styling, such as setting a
   TextAppearance on a TextView

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way I can use all three of them in the same project?

Comment: Yes of course. You can have multiple themes, styles and text appearance styles. apply theme to only part of the app, apply theme and style to another, apply just an style to a view, etc....